# NotePad++ найти и вырезать часть элемента кода и подставить эту часть в другой код

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, notepad++

В Notepad++ хочу найти все

```
mysql_fetch_array(вырезаемая_переменная);
```

и заменить их на

```
вырезанная_переменная->fetch_assoc();
```

Какой регуляркой можно это сделать?

Comment: Find: `mysql_fetch_array\((\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\);`, Replace: `$1->fetch_assoc();`.

Comment: не проще - `mysql_fetch_array\(\s*([^\)]+\s*)\);` ?

Comment: Саша, а что вы сами пробовали сделать? Опишите *проблему*, а не только *задачу*.

Comment: @Other спасибо отлично!

Comment: @splash58 смысл тот же, но радует что короче

Comment: @splash58, нет, не проще. Ваш вариант найдёт и `mysql_fetch_array(what? I'm not a variable, dude!);`. Моё определение из официальной маны.

Comment: @Other. не спорю. только добавьте возможные пробелы до и после. Народ любит их ставить в скобках :)

Comment: @splash58, домашняя работа для автора :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример регулярки, [предоставленный Other](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747976/notepad-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA#comment1150177_747976), содержит шаблон переменных PHP `\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff‌​]*`, который можно найти в [справочнике PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#121752). Для того, чтобы найти `(` и `)`, нужно экранировать скобки, иначе пара таких круглых скобок задаст шаблон захватываемой группы, которая в данном случае тоже должна присутствовать в выражении.

Для замены `mysql_fetch_array($abc);` на `$abc->fetch_assoc();` можно использовать

```
mysql_fetch_array\((\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff‌​]*)\);
```

Заменить на `$1->fetch_assoc\(\);`. Тут обязательно экранировать скобки тоже, потому что в противном случае круглые скобки зададут шаблон замены с условием.

**Подробности**

- `mysql_fetch_array\(` - подстрока `mysql_fetch_array(`
- `(\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff‌​]*)` - Захватываемая группа №1 (к значению которой можно обратиться с помощью обратной ссылки `$1` из шаблона замены):

  - `\$` - знак `$`
  - `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff]` - ASCII-буквы, `_` и знаки от `DEL` до `ÿ`
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff‌​]*` - то же, что выше, плюс ASCII-цифры.
- `\);` - `);`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]